# Rails tire search take datas by comparing with created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, filter, tire

I am using **tire** to search in my **Rails** application. I want to take data by comparing with created_at field. ie, giving conditions like created_at > '2013-01-01'

I read a method named **excludes**, But I couldn't see any tutorial for how to use this.

Comment: Please be more clear with the problem description: when you say "avoid some data", do you mean returning only certain amount of records (hint: size)? What do you mean by "comparing with created_at field" in this context (hint: sort)? Or do you want to return only certain properties of your documents (hint: fields or partial_fields)?

Comment: Sorry. What i meant is, i need to search through one model and the condition is , Fetch the datas which are created with in last 30 days.